# Why are the C++ perspective and new project options not available in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I installed the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" package from the Eclipse website. I work with C++ projects as well, so I used the "Install New Software..." menu option to install the "C/C++ Development Tools" package. After doing so and restarting Eclipse, the C++ perspective did not appear; clicking on the "Open Perspective" button did not show the "C/C++" option. I also found that I was unable to create a C++ project; the "C/C++" tree node did not appear in the New Project wizard. The Java perspective and new project options were available.

I verified that CDT was installed by going to the "Installed Installation Details" dialog - "C/C++ Development Tools" appeared in the "Installed Software" list. I tried uninstalling this package and reinstalled it again without success. I tried removing the Eclipse installation altogether and installing the "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers". There were no C/C++ options in this installation either. I checked the `.log` file in the workspace directory and found nothing unusual.

Why are the C/C++ features not available after installing the CDT feature in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path for this system Eclipse was installed on included a 1.3.1 version of the Java runtime environment and the Eclipse executable was using this version to run Eclipse. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any indication of this in Eclipse, nor any indication that anything failed.

Using the instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM), I changed the JVM to `javaw.exe` in a Java 7 installation. After doing so, the C/C++ perspective and new project options appeared in Eclipse.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Macbook - OSX - Mavericks. I don't know how to fix this. Any idea on it? Please help me here.

Comment: I tried add the jvm option to the right path, but no luck

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the similar problem with Eclipse-Luna(4.4) on Yosemite(10.10).
- NOT able to get the C/C++ perspective with JRE (8u25) or java 1.6 on Yosemite.

But I manage to get C/C++ perspective with the installation of JDK(8u25).

Comment: Thank for summarize it. Note: I don't know if that help in other environment!

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue.

I just installed java7 and restarted eclipse:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on Linux (CentOS 6.5 32-bit) with Eclipse Luna:

1. I installed standard Eclipse (eclipse-java-luna-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz)
2. In eclipse, under Help->Install New Software I added the p2 software repository to the list of sites: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.5
3. I installed C/C++ Development Tools and C/C++ Development Tools SDK
4. In CentOS, I also installed OpenJDK Development Environment java-1.7.0-devel-1:1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el6_5 (i686).
5. I edited eclipse.ini to increase the Xmx setting to 1024m from 256m, but I did not add a -vm property. In the Eclipse preferences after restarting, I verified it was using JDK 1.7.

The C++ perspective was not contained in the list of available perspectives.

But C++ Project **was** an option in the File->New menu, and when I chose it, Eclipse asked me if I wanted to use the C++ perspective. I said yes, and it appeared, and is now available in the perspectives list as well.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to install the latest JDK from Oracle. I had a fresh install of Yosemite and the Eclipse for Java developers. The C/C++ option showed up after the install and restart of Eclipse. Hope it helps!