# How can I fix my Eclipse + CDT configuration to enable CDT options?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have installed Eclipse Luna IDE for Java developers my OSX machine. This works fine. I have also installed the CDT. After installing the CDT I cannot see C/C++ build options, I cannot create a C/C++ project, and there is no option to switch to a C/C++ perspective.

Other information:
I have had Eclipse + CDT previously installed on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have successfully installed CDT by going to:

`Help` -> `About Eclipse` -> `Installation Details` -> `Installed Software`

You should have:

- C/C++ Autotools support
- C/C++ Autotools support Source
- C/C++ Development Tools
- C/C++ Development Tools SDK
- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

If that looks correct, you should be able to do this too:

`Window` -> `Show Perspective` -> `Other` -> `C/C++`

Comment: These are the steps I followed. However, I have no option to switch to a c/c++ perspective.

Comment: Have you tried solutions like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149696/no-c-option-after-install-eclipse-cdt) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783536/why-are-the-c-perspective-and-new-project-options-not-available-in-eclipse)?